# getting different results from converting an object to a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, .net, buffer

I am trying to create a messenger using asp.net core and WebSockets.I want the client to convert a `Message` object to `byte[]` and send it to the server by a WebSocket. But on the server-side, I can't deserialize the object that the client serialized. after some debugging, I found some differences between serialized buffers from the same objects on both sides.
actully, the serialized `byte[]` from `msg` object on the server-side is not the same as serialized `byte[]` from `msg` object on the client-side.

Here is my code on the server-side:

```
Message msg = new Message()
                {
                    Text="Test"
                };

var test = ObjectToByteArray(msg);



public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
 }



[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And exactly the same code on the client-side (my server-side is asp.net core 5 API and my client-side is Avalonia dotnet 6)

but here is peace of `var test` on the server-side (note that it has 170 bytes):

[image]

and here is peace of `var test` on the client-side (note that it has  160 bytes):
[image]

why they are different? how I can fix this bug?

Comment: Could you please check if this problem persists when both client and server use the same framework version? I mean e.g. testing both on dotnet 6

Comment: Don't use binaryFormatter! it is insecure, slow, and may not be backwards compatible across framework versions! Use some other binary serialization protocol. I have used protobuf .net, but there are plenty of other alternatives.

Comment: Does the client and the server uses the same assembly of Message class with the same version?

Comment: @JonasH can you help me for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943287/integers-change-during-decoding-protobuf) ?